# embeding PPT in the webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embed

I am working on the application that require documents to be embeded inside the webpage .
I want to embed a powerpoint slides inside the page, any pointer would be helping

The application i am working on is built on Ruby on Rails

I have checked google doc viewer but for some reason its not rendering the pdf/ppt from my application 
code used

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<%= URI.escape('http://myapp.com/doc_name.pdf') -%>&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: What's the response from docs.google.com?

Comment: Can you edit your app to post sample HTML of a real <iframe> sample? There's really very little in rails here, it's all HTML and google apps.

Comment: I can see the gview window but it says,
"Sorry, We are unable to retreive the document for viewing"

Comment: Seems like the issue was ... i was behind a proxy server that blocked the acess to site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was behind the firewall / proxy server that blocked the request to the site.... worked smoothly

Answering all the pending questions :)