# How to embed Microsoft powerpoint presentation and allow the user to slide in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, powerpoint

How to embed Microsoft powerpoint presentation and allow the user to slide pages in a Rails app

Answer (score 0):

A solution has been described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26101266/5726514 by [Matt Gibson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693349/matt-gibson)

You may have to use [Scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/) and display their embedded widget with rails.

Another solution is to use Google Drive and their PPT tools that can also be embedded with rails. ([embeding-ppt-in-the-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344549/embeding-ppt-in-the-webpage))